# How exactly do I use Metals and VS Code Debugger?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt, scala-metals

[Metals announced](https://scalameta.org/metals/blog/2020/01/10/cobalt.html#debugging) that "It is now possible to run and test directly from VS Code using the new "Run", "Test", "Debug" and "Debug test" buttons." There is a nice gif showing what it can do, and I don't know how to get to that point.

I tried to launch VS Code debugger with the following configurations in `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
           "type": "scala",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Untitled",
           "mainClass": "com.playZip.Unzip",
           "args": [],
           "jvmOptions": []
       }
    ]
}
```

and got this error message:

```
Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'scala' (extension might have failed to activate)
```

Somebody on [Gitter scalameta/metals](https://gitter.im/scalameta/metals) had this problem and the answer was that he needs Bloop to support utest and I think mine does because there's a file `.bloop/play-zip-test.json` in my sbt project, but I'm not 100% if my Bloop supports utest and what to do if it doesn't. I tried running `bloop utest` and it failed because I don't have Bloop CLI installed. I have Bloop that comes with Metals.

Comment: Any reason for not installing the whole bloop server and cli?

Comment: In general, I haven't encountered a reason to install Bloop CLI. I think Bloop server came with Metals (correct me if I'm wrong).

I didn't want to go down the path of learning more about Bloop... I think the problem is that I literally cannot find simple, step-by-step directions for how to use the debugger. Google has only pointed me to cases where people knew how to use the debugger, and just encountered a problem... 
I realize SO isn't meant to cover the basics. But the Metals docs that was meant for that, isn't doing that.

Comment: Yeah **metals** will start an embedded server, however running a system-wide server has two advantages: 1. All clients connect to it which increases performance. 2. you do not need to use **sbt** for compiling / testing / running. - I just clicked the button that said `run debug` over the main and it worked for me.

Comment: Hmmm... I will consider installing the whole bloop server and cli. Thank you.

Comment: @vivian have you been able to find a solution to this problem? I'm currently having the same issue, which I encountered because I was getting tired of having to go and click "run" every time. I've been trying to find a solution for over an hour and haven't been able to find anything useful neither on GitHub, SO or the Scala Metals doc.

Comment: @cliesens, I haven't had the time to troubleshoot. Let's stay in touch. I will ping you if I find a solution. :\

Comment: @vivian Thank you, I appreciate it. I'll do the same.

Comment: @cliesens, I followed Mario's hello world example (he wrote an answer), and I got the same problem. I then updated Metals, made sure my Scala version was compatible with Metals (Metals doesn't work with Scala 2.13 yet), provided a Java Home path for Metals (see shunsvineyard's answer below), and that still didn't work. shunsvineyard did show me how to look at Metal's logs so I just made a plan to debug the next day. FYI, the error message was `Java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`.

The next day, I turned on my computer and tried to recreate the bug and everything just worked.

Comment: I have no idea why it just worked the next day...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Document how to run or debug applications #2005](https://github.com/scalameta/metals/pull/2005) added official debugging documentation at [Running and debugging your code](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html#running-and-debugging-your-code) which documents two approaches

1. via code lenses `run | debug`
   [image]
2. via a `launch.json` configuration

---

Here is a hello world example how to debug a test using VSC and Metals via `launch.json` approach. We will use
lihaoyi/utest library and set a breakpoint in a test.

1. Execute `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` to create correct project structure
2. `Open...` sbt project with VSC or simply `cd` into project and execute `code .`
3. Replace ScalaTest with utest in `build.sbt`

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % "0.7.2" % "test",
   testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.Framework")
   ```
4. Replace `test/scala/example/HelloSpec.scala` with `HelloTests.scala`

   ```
   package example

   import utest._

   object HelloTests extends TestSuite{
     val tests = Tests{
       test("test1"){
         1
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Import sbt build with `View | Command Palette... | Metals: Import Build`
6. Put a breakpoint at line 8 and click `Run and Debug`

   [image]
7. Select `Test Suite` for `Pick the kind of class to debug`
8. Leave empty for `Enter the name of the build target`
9. Write `example.HelloTests` for `Enter the name of the class to debug`
10. Write `Debug example.HelloTests` for `Enter the name of configuration`
11. This should create `.vscode/launch.json`

    ```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "scala",
                "name": "Debug example.HelloTests",
                "request": "launch",
                "testClass": "example.HelloTests"
            }
        ]
    }
    ```
12. Now you should be able to `Start Debugging` by clicking the green triangle and stop at the breakpoint

    [image]

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. :( But you did answer the question and a simple example that works on your computer. It's helpful to have a simple example that I know works on other computers.

Comment: @vivian Metals now provides official documentation for debugging. Please see edited  answer.

Comment: I'm using Gradle + JUnit. It's not clear how VSCode knows how to run a utest test suite. I get `Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'scala'. (extension might have failed to active)`.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use utest to be able to debug ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if your problem is solved, but I did see the same issue before. To get more information about the error, you can check the Metals output. See the picture below:
From the output tab, select Metals. More detail of the error should be available.
[image]

In my case, the reason I got this error (`Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'scala' (extension might have failed to activate)` ) is because the Java installed in my machine does not support JDI.

```
Message: Debugging is not supported because bloop server is running on a JRE /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre with no support for Java Debug Interface: 'JDI implementation is not provided by the vendor'. To enable debugging, install a JDK and restart the bloop server.
```

I guess your case is probably the same. To solve it, just install a Java implementation supports JDI. For example, `openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14` works fine with Metals on Ubuntu. You can do this to install it.

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

If it still not works, make sure `Metals: Java Home` in VS Code settings points to the right Java version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and it came down to the `buildTarget`. I have a multiple module project. When I looked at the metals logs this is what I saw:

```
Caused by: scala.MatchError: scala.meta.internal.metals.debug.BuildTargetNotFoundException: Build target not found:  (of class scala.meta.internal.metals.debug.BuildTargetNotFoundException)
```

My Scala project

```
/client_accounts
   /migrations
   /app
```

Updated the launch.json to  `"buildTarget": "app",` and it worked. Error reporting could be a bit better.

So if you get this error look at the logs for the root cause.